# How to handle nested "vendor" directories in Go packages?

Tags: go, package-managers

I'm writing an application and import some package `B`. This package has the `vendor` directory inside which, in turn, contains package `C`. I also want to use that package `C` in my app directly.

So I decided to use `glide` package manager. It downloads both `B` and `C` into `myapp/vendor` directory, but keeps `myapp/vendor/B/vendor/C` inside. So when I build my app, it builds with two different versions of C (also with `myapp/vendor/C`).

How to avoid that?

1) Either, is there a package manager that handles that? `govend` seems to with its `--prune` argument, but it doesn't respect the versions of these `C` packages.

2) Or, how to make `glide` properly handle the nested `vendor` directories?

**Edit**

My example is `https://github.com/orloffm/flat`. It uses `cat` and - indirectly - `toy` packages. `cat` has some *older version* of `toy` vendored and commited into repository. I do `glide create && glide install` and end up with this:

```
.
├── flat.go
├── glide.lock
├── glide.yaml
└── vendor
    └── github.com
        └── orloffm
            ├── cat
            │   ├── cat.go
            │   ├── vendor
            │   │   └── github.com
            │   │       └── orloffm
            │   │           └── toy
            │   │               └── toy.go
            │   └── vendor.yml
            └── toy
                └── toy.go
```

I don't want to have nested `vendor` directory with `toy`.

Comment: I don't use `glide` right now, but are you sure you have the latest version? Just a quick glance at the docs shows `"Because of this Glide flattens the dependency tree into a single top level vendor/ directory."`

Comment: As JimB stated, most current vendoring tools that I've used automatically flatten the dependency tree.  This is practically required, because the same package imported from two different unique paths are actually considered two different unique packages, as you found.  I know `govendor` does it by default.

Comment: @Kaedys +1 for govendor.  I've used it in quite a few projects.

Comment: Flattening the vendor directory is indeed a core glide feature; can you also include the exact glide invocation you're using and what your config file looks like?

Comment: @SamWhited It is `https://github.com/orloffm/flat`. It uses `cat` and indirectly `toy`. But `cat` has some old version of `toy` vendored. I do `glide create` and `glide install` and get vendor/cat/vendor/toy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to install and run your `flat` program by making the following  changes (also sent you a PR https://github.com/orloffm/flat/pull/1):

1) flat.go needs to import "github.com/orloffm/toy" because of `new(toy.RubberToy)` - otherwise it doesn't compile

2) add `glide.yaml` file that list both "cat" and "toy" libraries as dependencies:

```
package: github.com/orloffm/flat
import:
- package: github.com/orloffm/cat
- package: github.com/orloffm/toy
```

3) run `glide install --strip-vcs --strip-vendor` (or the equivalent shortcut `glide install -s -v`) to install packages and remove nested `vendor/` directories  (I'm using glide version 0.11.0-dev installed with `go get -u github.com/Masterminds/glide`; `glide install --help` shows the `--strip-vendor` option).

4) GOBIN=$PWD go install && ./flat produces

```
Cat pushes the toy.
The toy makes a very loud noise.
```

I think the best would be **not** to include the `vendor` directory into your **libraries** - this messes things up and makes life more difficult for the library users (for example, need to remember to use additional options to `glide`). Let the "clients" of those libraries - `package main` packages - either to vendor all the dependencies (including transitive ones) or specify them in a configuration such as `glide.yaml` and let the tool (glide) to fetch and install them properly.

Comment: That sorts things out, thank you very much. I was a bit confused comparing it to all other tools.