# Glide or dep dependencies issue, dependencies in vendor are not flat

Tags: go, glide-golang

Related code is as follow:

```
import (
    core "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/legacyscheme"
)
...

func PodExec(clusterId string, namespace string, podName string, containerName string, cmd string) (){

    ...

    req.VersionedParams(&core.PodExecOptions{
        Container: containerName,
        Command:   []string{"bash", "-c", cmd},
        Stdin:     false,
        Stdout:    true,
        Stderr:    true,
        TTY:       false,
    }, legacyscheme.ParameterCodec) //FIXME Here is the concerned code.

}

...
```

`glide.yaml` is as follow:

```
package: xxx-k8s-apiserver
import:
- package: github.com/astaxie/beego
  version: v1.10.1
- package: k8s.io/api
  subpackages:
  - apps/v1
  - core/v1
- package: k8s.io/apimachinery
  subpackages:
  - pkg/api/errors
  - pkg/api/resource
  - pkg/apis/meta/v1
  - pkg/util/intstr
  - pkg/util/yaml
- package: k8s.io/client-go
  version: v10.0.0
```

When I run `go build` in my project, sth goes wrong like this.

```
# xxx-k8s-apiserver/models
models/pod.go:82:3: cannot use legacyscheme.ParameterCodec (type "xxx-k8s-apiserver/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime".ParameterCodec) as type "xxx-k8s-apiserver/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime".ParameterCodec in argument to req.VersionedParams:
        "xxx-k8s-apiserver/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime".ParameterCodec does not implement "xxx-k8s-apiserver/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime".ParameterCodec (wrong type for DecodeParameters method)
                have DecodeParameters(url.Values, "xxx-k8s-apiserver/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime/schema".GroupVersion, "xxx-k8s-apiserver/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime".Object) error
                want DecodeParameters(url.Values, "xxx-k8s-apiserver/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime/schema".GroupVersion, "xxx-k8s-apiserver/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime".Object) error
```

Then I see into the `./vendor` directory, it seems like `glide` or `dep` somehow falsely organized the dependency path. Dependencies are not flat because there is another `vendor` in the vendor path `./vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle nested "vendor" directories in Go packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597046/how-to-handle-nested-vendor-directories-in-go-packages)

Answer (score 0):

[How to handle nested "vendor" directories in Go packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597046/how-to-handle-nested-vendor-directories-in-go-packages)

Typical nested vendor issue. Still no clues why `--strip-vendor` is not true by default in `glide install`, it causes so much inconvenience.

It's a duplicate issue.